# Software to clean unnecessary data from my PC without making any kind of damage?

Tags: windows, windows-10, data, hard-disk, memory-management

I do have a lot of unnecessary data in my **C-drive**, some of them are from previously installed software and some are just some temporary files...

Can you suggest me some good software to clean them **without making any damage** to my ***Windows 10 PC***.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a third party software to achieve what you are asking. Windows 10 has built in features that enable you to clean junk and free up space in your PC.

Simply in the search bar search for 'storage settings' and click 'temporary files'. Wait for a couple of minutes for it to stop loading and then you can see what you can delete that won't harm your PC.

'Storage settings' also has a section where you can delete apps that you might not need.